# How can I detect each line in an image full of lines on GNU/Octave?

Tags: image, line, octave

I have an image like this one:[image: A lot of lines]

How can i select a single line from it, and them, select all of them individually?

The image is a double variable signal with value 1 at the lines and 0 elsewhere, and i want to select the lines so I can calculate the length of them, and the integral of something along them.

Comment: How do you mean "select" a single or all line? If your image is a bw image and there are no crossing lines you can simply do a bwlabel (octave forge image package). How thick are the lines? Perhaps you want a skeleton algorithm first.

Comment: The problem with bwlabel is that the lines are broken sometimes by only one pixel, and them bwlabel "sees" them as two separate lines. I'm interested in a better way of handling this kind of things.

Comment: A typical way to connect these is an erode, delate cycle (this might sound inverse because you have black objects on white background)

Answer (score 0):

if the problem is just "lines too thin", you can first do a morphological math operation "dilation" with radius = 1 pixel then run bwlabel.
http://octave.sourceforge.net/image/function/imdilate.html